# How to include an external jar file to aar file in Android

Tags: android, gradle, jar, sdk, aar

I want to develop a solution that allows me to use an external jar library in an SDK generated in aar file for an Android project.

What I have as inputs :

SDK : "de.xx.sdk:xxx-android-v1.0.0"

external library : "libs/xxxx-v1.0.0"

what I found out in my investigation is how to exclude a library from project like the following :

```
implementation('android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'
    }
```

Is there something similar to write in gradle file how to include a library instead of exclude it.

```
implementation('de.xx.sdk:xxx-android-v1.0.0') {
        include group: 'libs/xxxx-v1.0.0'
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: add jar file  inside lib folder

Comment: You'll need to create a maven repository instead.

Comment: could you explain me more how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to put your jar into a module (File->New->New Module->Import JAR/AAR Package) and then add the module as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

> `implementation('de.xx.sdk:xxx-android-v1.0.0') {
>               include group: 'libs/xxxx-v1.0.0'
>           }`

You can't do it in this way.

Something like `exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'listenablefuture'` is possible because you have an artifact with a **pom file** published in a **maven repo**.
In the pom file there is the list of the transitive dependencies, and if there is a match with the `group/module` gradle is able to exclude it.

To achieve something similar, **you have to publish the lib a in maven repo** with a group/name (it can't be lib/....v1.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old, but it might can help the others

can add this snippet to build.gradle

https://gist.github.com/stepio/824ef073447eb8d8d654f22d73f9f30b